# Why doesn't my scanner work?

Tags: python

Method of sending udp package

```
def udp_sender(subnet,magic_message):
    time.sleep(5)
    sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    for ip in IPNetwork(subnet):
        try:
            sender.sendto(magic_message.encode("utf-8"),("%s"%ip,65212))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
           # pass
```

Setting before scan:

```
if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP

sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket_protocol)

sniffer.bind((host,0))
sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,socket.IP_HDRINCL,1)

if os.name == "nt":
    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_ON)

t = threading.Thread(target=udp_sender,args=(subnet,magic_message))
t.start()
```

Scan and receive icmp package:

IP and ICMP are class that I defined:

```
try:
    while True:
        raw_buffer = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)[0]
        ip_header = IP(raw_buffer)
        #print("Protocol: %s %s -> %s"%        (ip_header.protocol,ip_header.src_address,ip_header.dst_address))
        if ip_header.protocol == "ICMP":
        offset = ip_header.ihl*4
        buf = raw_buffer[offset:offset+sizeof(ICMP)]
        icmp_header = ICMP(buf)
       # print("ICMP -> Type:%d Code:%d"%(icmp_header.type,icmp_header.code))
        if icmp_header.code == 3 and icmp_header.type == 3:
            if IPAddress(ip_header.src_address) in IPNetwork(subnet):
                if raw_buffer[len(raw_buffer)-len(magic_message):].decode("utf-8") == magic_message:
                    print("Host up:%s"%ip_header.src_address)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if os.name == "nt":
        sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL,socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

However, it doesn't work and only host up my own ip.....

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  "It doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: What value is the `host` variable name set to?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule `host` is ip of my computer